# Send post with Spark Framework

Tags: java, rest, post, web, spark-java

From what I understand the [Spark Framework for Java](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html) makes it very easy to run a restful server that accepts, POST, GET, etc..

Is there an easy way to send a POST out using the spark library?

The idea is to handle requests asynchronously and to respond via a callback. That callback requires an asynchronous post to come from my application to another web server.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add another library to act as the rest client. Spark is intended to be a rest server.

Comment: I would suggest you to check [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html) as a Rest Client for your application. It has the same idea as spark, which is being easy to code and lightweight to run. I'm using it in a JavaFX project.